# Inkscape, align objects top has space between objects

Tags: inkscape

I'm trying to align object in inkscape to make a heart shape but when alligning there is a very small space between the two objects. How can I get rid of that space ?

[image]

As you can see in the picture, where the object half circle meets the square there is a very tiny white line. That's what I want to get rid off.

Answer (score 1):

this is a limitation in the rendering of Inkscape, which uses anti-aliasing. This gap is not really there, which you can confirm by zooming in. It won't grow. A work around is to give the objects a tiny stroke of 1 px.